# Laravel Package with dependency package

Tags: laravel, package

I am developing laravel package. Here is my composer.json file. in my local package, i am adding **opentok/opentok** dependency package. So after running composer, vendor folder created in my local package. I have included my service provider in config/app.php file. but i am unable to use dependency package class in my local package. Here is my local package composer.json file.

```
 {
    "name": "cast/talk",
    "description": "video caht",
    "require": {
        "opentok/opentok": "2.5.x"
    }
}
```

My serviceprovider

```
<?php

namespace cast\Talk;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class TalkServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
        include __DIR__.'/routes.php';
        $this->app->make('cast\Talk\TalkController');
    }
}
```

my package controller

```
<?php

namespace cast\Talk;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use OpenTok\OpenTok;
use OpenTok\MediaMode;
use OpenTok\Session as OpentokSession;
use OpenTok\Role;

class TalkController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {

        $opentok = new OpenTok('xxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');

        $sessionOptions = array(
            'mediaMode' => MediaMode::ROUTED
        );
        $session = $opentok->createSession($sessionOptions);

        echo $sessionId = $session->getSessionId();die;
    }

}
```

routes.php

```
<?php

Route::get('members', 
  'cast\talk\TalkController@index');
```

when i access members page i am getting Class 'OpenTok\OpenTok' not found

So how to work with dependency package in laravel package?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I am running into something exactly like this

Comment: no. I have added directly in my main package.json

Comment: I think I found a solution for you. Try `\cast\talk\TalkController@index` instead of just  companies `cast\talk\TalkController@index`  (the initial \) was what was missing in my code